# System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0 conflict

Tags: file, load

Compilation error in C#

In case You get error with System.net.http at runtime stating "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0". Something like

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]

Answer (score 0):

for me, I have different packages using different versions. It started when one package added the **'bindingRedirect'** to app.config file.
Problem resolved after I removed bindingRedirect
***bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"***
from app.config file.
So remove entry like below
      `<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" /> </dependentAssembly>`

Answer (score 0):

I have this old WCF project, in which somebody added a new Nuget Package (Nlog)
This package depends on System.Net.Http 4.3.4, but for some reason, compiler only finded 4.2.0.0

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly  "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

```
1>  Unified Dependency "System.Net.Http, Version=4.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>      Using this version instead of original version "4.1.1.3" in "C:\SomeFolder\packages\NLog.Targets.Seq.2.1.0\lib\net462\NLog.Targets.Seq.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "Web.config".
1>      Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=4.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

I've solved by deleting the dependentAssembly in web.config file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```